# On the calculation of $L=\frac \lambda{\mu-\lambda}$

Tags: operations-research, queueing-theory

I have a question regarding the calculation of $L=\frac \lambda{\mu-\lambda}$

In the exercise, $\lambda=30$ and I think $\mu=30\cdot1$.

Am I right?

However this will lead to an indetermination in the denominator of $L$.

How should I prooced here?

Please help me.

[image]

This exercise is from *Operational Research* by Hillier

Answer (score 2):

No, the value of $\mu$ is $60/1.5=40$ per hour for the current system.

Comment: The question says for "current mode of operation" where service time is 1.5 minutes. Note that 1 minute service time will also be 60/hr.